# Rust Generics, "`T` may not live long enough"

Tags: rust, lua

I'm trying to imbed Lua into Rust using [Mlua](https://github.com/khvzak/mlua). Using its [guided tour](https://github.com/khvzak/mlua/blob/master/examples/guided_tour.rs), I successfully loaded and evaluated a chunk of Lua code. My next goal is to combine this with opening a file and reading its contents. This is where things get problematic:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use mlua::{Lua, UserData};
use std::fs;

pub struct LuaManager {
    lua_state: Lua
}

impl LuaManager {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        LuaManager {
            lua_state: Lua::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn eval<T>(&self, chunk: &str) -> Result<T> where T: Clone + UserData {
        let v = self.lua_state.load(chunk).eval::<T>()?;
        Ok(v)
    }
}
```

Since scripts can return literally anything, I thought a trait-locked generic annotation would solve the issue: The problem is this:

```
Error generated by rustc: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough... so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds...
```

For reference, here is the function signature as defined in lua.rs:

```
pub fn eval<R: FromLuaMulti<'lua>>(self) -> Result<R>
```

I don't understand why I'm having this issue. I've looked this up and this question pertained to user-created types, which to my knowledge I'm not doing... so what is the problem here? It's clear that things like `<i32>` won't die anytime soon. Cargo did suggest adding a static lifetime annotation, but doing some research into it points me to trying to solve the problem without using it first, since in 99% of cases you actually can get away without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately in this case it seems like `'static` is really required.

[`Lua::load()`](https://docs.rs/mlua/latest/mlua/struct.Lua.html#method.load) takes `&'lua self` and returns [`Chunk<'lua, '_>`](https://docs.rs/mlua/latest/mlua/struct.Chunk.html). [`Chunk::<'lua, '_>::eval::<R>()`](https://docs.rs/mlua/latest/mlua/struct.Chunk.html#method.eval) requires `R: FromLuaMulti<'lua>`. [`FromLuaMulti<'lua>`](https://docs.rs/mlua/latest/mlua/trait.FromLuaMulti.html) is [implemented for `T: FromLua<'lua>`](https://docs.rs/mlua/latest/mlua/trait.FromLuaMulti.html#impl-FromLuaMulti%3C%27lua%3E-2). [`FromLua<'lua>`](https://docs.rs/mlua/latest/mlua/trait.FromLua.html) [is implemented for `T: UserData`](https://docs.rs/mlua/latest/mlua/trait.FromLua.html#impl-FromLua%3C%27lua%3E-8), however it requires `T: 'static` (and also `T: Clone`, but this is irrelevant).

Comment: Also, see [#2 on this list](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program) for an explanation of what `T: 'static` actually means. (In short, it means that `T` is "owned", like a `String` or a `u32`, i.e. that it doesn't contain references to the caller's environment. The `'static` bound is not unreasonable for this use case.)

Comment: @user4815162342 Oh, I thought the OP knows it.